# Construct SLR Parse table problems

Tags: compilers, parsers

Consider the augmented grammar G is:

```
S` -> S
S -> a
S -> (T)
T -> T,S
T -> S
```

I have tried to construct parse table. But, when I read '(' nonterminal Symbol (item 3), there is no action table elements either 'shift' or 'reduce'.

```
I3:
S -> (.T)
T -> .T,S
T -> .S
```

so I can't construe '(a,(a,a))' in this Parse table.
then is it ambiguous grammar? or I wrong the answer?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing items in I3? There is a dot before S in one of the production.

Answer (score -2):

I3 productions are:
S->(.T)
T->.T,S
T->.S
here you need to add closure of S
S->.a
S->.(T)

Comment: This looks a bit thin. Can you elaborate, in particular w.r.t. "why"?